# Module Federation App and React Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, webpack-module-federation

I am new to Module Federation. So just had a very basic question regarding structuring a React App to support Module Federation.

So I have index.js as

```
import('./bootstrap');
export { };
```

bootstrap.jsx as

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import BootstrapApp from './BootstrapApp';
ReactDOM.render(<BootstrapApp />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

BootstrapApp.js as

```
import App from './App';

function BootstrapApp() {
  return (
    <>
      <App />

    </>
  );
}

export default BootstrapApp;
```

My App.js is as below

```
import { Route, Routes, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import {HashRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <div>HOST APP: <br /></div>
    <Router>
      <Route exact path="/my-inquiry">
        <MyInquiryWrapper />
      </Route>
    </Router>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Now my question is for most of the React apps, I have not seen the BootstrapApp wrapper.

So is the BootstrapApp something which is required for the Module federation implementation ?

Also in the BootstrapApp of some of the projects, I have seen below definition;

```
<Router>
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/*' element={<App />}></Route>
          </Routes>
      </Router>
```

Is this also something which is related to Module Federation OR not required for Module Federation ?

Answer (score 0):

> Now my question is for most of the React apps, I have not seen the
> `BootstrapApp` wrapper.
>
> So is the `BootstrapApp` something which is required for the Module
> federation implementation?

No, the `BootstrapApp` appears to only exist as a way to hold some global app state and/or logic to provide to your `App` component. You can see this in the next part of your question:

> Also in the BootstrapApp of some of the projects, I have seen below
> definition;
>
> ```
> <Router>
>   <Routes>
>     <Route path='/*' element={<App />}></Route>
>   </Routes>
> </Router>
> ```

Here the `BootstrapApp` component is rendering and wrapping the `App` component with a router so the entire sub-ReactTree rendered by `App` has the routing context available to it. This allows all `Routes`, `Route`, `Link`, `NavLink`, etc components, and all React-Router-DOM hooks to work.

I suspect `BootstrapApp` is intended to provide some default Bootstrap UI styling.

Note also that it's not necessary to render `App` on a route itself, just rendering as a child/descendent of the `Router` is sufficient.

Complete example if `App` wasn't already rendering its own `HashRouter` component:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
...
import App from './App';

function BootstrapApp() {
  // any global business logic/loaders/etc

  return (
    // ...additional Context providers, etc...
      <Router>
        <App />
      </Router>
    //...
  );
}

export default BootstrapApp;
```

Comment: Thanks...so in terms of loading the app....Say when user first loads http://localhost:3000, does the execution not go over index.js -> BootstrapApp -> App...But instead directly loads the App component....
I understand that the build output is different and has index.html....But just trying to understand the internal flow on first load...

Comment: Also, I was just asking this question in terms of Module Federation, as it explicitly defines a remoteEntry.js in the configuration

Comment: @copenndthagen That seems correct if index.js is the `ReactDom.render` entry point rendering `BootstrapApp`, which then renders `App`. This all won't be rendered until the parent app is on the correct route to render the sub-app.